# Css grid content doesn't fit cell vertically

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So i'm having some trouble with my layout using Css Grid.
Here is a CodePen of my current layout :

https://codepen.io/jbeaudoin11/pen/zMOGGd

My goal is to have `glitch-card` with a dynamic height/width and fit the `content` cell. It works like a charm horizontally, the scrollbar shows up in the card `container`. But i'm not able to make it work vertically.

In my CodePen you can see the cyan border which represent where it should fit (should stop at the bottom of the window), but it doesn't and make `content` overflow the window.

Comment: That code is a bit of a mess. Could you create a pen with a minimal problem?

Comment: That's pretty much the minimum :(

Comment: Except you have all these extra divs and styles that don't need to be included in the problem formulation. Remove unnecessary elements until you can't, but still exhibit the problem.

Comment: Those aren't extra divs, it's part of the problem. I really don't know how i could remove stuff sorry.

Comment: Even just simplifying it to this works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEKxrE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive adding this lines to your glitch-card css does the trick

```
display: inline-grid;
overflow: hidden;
```

Check the CodePen: https://codepen.io/remigioamc/pen/xQKZWq

Comment: Work like a charm ! I've been debugging that for 6 hours THANK YOU !